# width em slide show responsivo

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estou construindo o responsivo de um um projeto de estudo,e estou com um problema no slide show dele, as imagens que estão dentro do slide show não acompanham a responsividade e quebram,que propriedade posso usar para consertar esse erro?
Códigos abaixo:

```js
var slideItem=0;
window.onload =function() {
     setInterval(passarSlide, 2000);
 var slidewidth =document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth;
 var objs =document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
 for(var i in objs) {
  objs[i].style.width=slidewidth+'px';
    }  
}
function passarSlide() {
var slidewidth =document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth;

if(slideItem>= 3) {
  slideItem=0
    } else {
     slideItem++;
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow_area")[0].style.marginLeft= "-"+(slidewidth * slideItem)+"px";
}
function mudarSlide(pos) {
 slideItem = pos;
 var slidewidth =document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow_area")[0].style.marginLeft= "-"+(slidewidth * slideItem)+"px";
```

```css
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: helvetica;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            
            .topo {
                height: 30px;
                background-color: #303030;
            }
            
            .topoint {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                height: 30px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .topoleft {
                width: 50%;
                height: 30px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            .toporight {
                width: 50%;
                height: 28px;
                float: right;
                text-align: right;
                margin-top: 2px;
            }
            
            .topoleft ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
            }
            
            .topoleft li {
                float: left;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                margin-left: 8px;
                margin-right: 8px;
            }
            
            .topoleft li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #FFF;
            }
            
            .topoleft li .ativo {
                color: blue;
            }
            
            .topobusca {
                width: 110px;
                height: 26px;
                outline: 0;
            }
            
            .toporight a {
                float: right;
            }
            
            .toporight input {
                float: right;
            }
            
            .toporight img {
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            
            .topo2 {
                height: 95px;
            }
            
            .topo2int {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                height: 95px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .logo {
                width: 230px;
                height: 65px;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
            
            .topo2 .banner {
                width: 650px;
                height: 80px;
                float: right;
                margin-top: 7px;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                font-size: 40px;
                color: #fff;
                line-height: 80px;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: roboto;
            }
            
            .menu {
                height: 40px;
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            
            .menuint {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                height: 40px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .menu ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
                position: absolute;
            }
            
            .menu li {
                float: left;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 40px;
                padding-left: 8px;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }
            
            .menu li:hover .submenu {
                display: block;
            }
            
            .menu a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            .submenu {
                width: 140px;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                display: none;
            }
            
            .submenuitem {
                width: 140px;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
            
            .submenuitem:hover {
                background-color: #ff5555;
                width: 130px;
            }
            
            .ultimasnoticias {
                height: 40px;
            }
            
            .ultimasnoticiasint {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                height: 40px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .ultnoticiasarea {
                height: 28px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            
            .ultnoticiastitulo {
                background-color: #ff0000;
                color: #fff;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                border-top-left-radius: 2px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            
            .ultnoticiasnoticia {
                color: #000;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                border-top-right-radius: 2px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
            }
            
            .containerint {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .leftside {
                width: 750px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            .rightside {
                width: 278px;
                min-height: 300px;
                float: right;
                margin-left: 12px;
            }
            
            .widget {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background-color: #fff;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            
            .widget_titulo {
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                background-color: #ddd;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding-left: 5px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            
            .widget_conteudo {
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }
            
            .noticia_item {
                font-size: 14px;
                margin: 0px 10px;
                padding: 10px 0px;
                text-align: left;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            
            .noticia_item a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000;
            }
            
            .slideshow {
                height: 335px;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            
            .slideshow_area {
                width: 10000px;
                height: 335px;
                transition: all 1s;
            }
            
            .slide {
                height: 335px;
                float: left;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                background-size: cover;
            }
            
            .slide img {
                height: 335px;
                width: 750px;
            }
            
            .slideinfo {
                position: relative;
                top: -70px;
                height: 70px;
                background-image: url('../images/slideshow_bg.png');
                background-size: auto 70px;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
            
            .slideinfo_titulo {
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #fff;
                padding-top: 20px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
            
            .slideinfo_subtitulo {
                font-size: 13px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                color: #fff;
            }
            
            .bolls {
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: 15px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
            
            .boll {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: #d0d1cc;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            .noticiaarea1 {
                width: 420px;
                height: 420px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            .noticiaitem1 {
                height: 220px;
            }
            
            .noticia_image {
                width: 390px;
                height: 220px;
                float: left;
                padding: 3px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin-top: 4px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            
            .texto_descritivo {
                font-size: 30px;
                width: 390px;
                text-align: left;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            
            .texto_subdescritivo {
                color: #ccc;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: left;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            
            .noticiaarea2 {
                width: 310px;
                height: 420px;
                float: right;
            }
            
            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
            
            .noticiaitem {
                text-align: left;
                height: 88px;
                margin-bottom: 14px;
            }
            
            .noticia_img {
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 3px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            .noticiatitulo {
                float: left;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                font-size: 16px;
                width: 216px;
            }
            
            .noticiainfo {
                float: left;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                color: #999;
                width: 216px;
            }
            
            .footer {
                position: absolute;
                height: 35px;
                width: 100%;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            
            .footerint {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1040px;
                height: 35px;
                margin: auto;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 35px;
                font-family: roboto;
            }
            
            @media only screen and (max-width:1057px) {
                .topoint,
                .topo2int,
                .menuint,
                .ultimasnoticiasint,
                .containerint,
                .footerint {
                    max-width: 890px;
                }
                .leftside {
                    width: 600px;
                }
                .slide img {
                    width: ;
                }
                .noticiaarea1 {
                    width: 280px;
                }
                .noticia_image {
                    width: 250px;
                }
                .noticia_image img {
                    width: 250px;
                }
                .texto_descritivo {
                    width: 250px;
                    font-size: 25px;
                }
            }
```

[Um tiulo de teste para esse slide
                           Subtitulo de teste para esse slide](http://br.ufc.com/)
                        
                     
                     
            
                
                    
                    
                        [Um tiulo de teste para esse slide
                        Subtitulo de teste para esse slide](http://sicnoticias.sapo.pt/)
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                    
                        [Um tiulo de teste para esse slide
                        Subtitulo de teste para esse slide](https://www.nfl.com/)
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                    
                        [Um tiulo de teste para esse slide
                        Subtitulo de teste para esse slide](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/index.html)
                    
                
            
            
            
            
                NOTÍCIAS
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum texto descritivo que vai aparecer por aqui abaixo dessa imagem
                             1250 likes 500 comentários
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                    
                    
                
            
            
                NOTÍCIAS RECENTES
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum texto descritivo que vai aparecer por aqui abaixo dessa imagem
                             1250 likes 500 comentários
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                        
                            
                                
                            
                            Algum titulo qualquer
                            500 comentários
                        
                    
                    
                
            
            
                
                    © 2018. Todos os direitos reservados
                
            
            
            
                
                    SOCIAL
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
                
                    ULTIMAS NOTÍCIAS
                    
                        
                            Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                             aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.
                          
                             
                             Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                             aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.
                          
                           
                             Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                             aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.
                          
                           
                             Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                             aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.
                          
                           
                             Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                             aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.
                          
                      
                 
                    
                       PUBLICIDADADE
                      
                          
                      
                 
                 
                       ENCONTRE-NOS NO FACEBOOK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar responsividade não se deve usar dimensões fixas em elementos que deverão se autoajustar. Geralmente se usa porcentagens, como: `width: 100%`, `max-width: LARGURA MÁX[px|%]` ou `vw` (largura do *viewport*).

Por exemplo, aqui você está usando uma largura fixa para as imagens:

```
.slide img {
    height: 335px;
    width: 750px;
}
```

E aqui também uma largura fixa numa `div`:

```
.leftside {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Fiz algumas alterações no CSS (vide comentários no mesmo) para que a parte do slide fique responsiva, mas necessitará ainda de algum ajuste conforme a sua necessidade:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.topo {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #303030;
}

.topoint {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
}

.topoleft {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.toporight {
    width: 50%;
    height: 28px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.topoleft ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.topoleft li {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.topoleft li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

.topoleft li .ativo {
    color: blue;
}

.topobusca {
    width: 110px;
    height: 26px;
    outline: 0;
}

.toporight a {
    float: right;
}

.toporight input {
    float: right;
}

.toporight img {
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.topo2 {
    height: 95px;
}

.topo2int {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 230px;
    height: 65px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.topo2 .banner {
    width: 650px;
    height: 80px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: roboto;
}

.menu {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.menuint {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu li {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.menu li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}

.menu a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu {
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: none;
}

.submenuitem {
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.submenuitem:hover {
    background-color: #ff5555;
    width: 130px;
}

.ultimasnoticias {
    height: 40px;
}

.ultimasnoticiasint {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
}

.ultnoticiasarea {
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.ultnoticiastitulo {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ultnoticiasnoticia {
    color: #000;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

.containerint {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: auto;
}

.leftside {
    width: 750px;
    float: left;
}

.rightside {
    width: 278px;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.widget {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.widget_titulo {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.widget_conteudo {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.noticia_item {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.noticia_item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.slideshow {
    height: 335px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slideshow_area {
    width: 10000px;
    height: 335px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.slide {
    height: 335px;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%; /* adicionado */
    max-width: 750px; /* adicionado */
}

.slide img {
    height: 335px;
    /* width: 750px; removido */
    width: 100%;/* adicionado */
}

.slideinfo {
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url('../images/slideshow_bg.png');
    background-size: auto 70px;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.slideinfo_titulo {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.slideinfo_subtitulo {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.bolls {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.boll {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #d0d1cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.noticiaarea1 {
    width: 420px;
    height: 420px;
    float: left;
}

.noticiaitem1 {
    height: 220px;
}

.noticia_image {
    width: 390px;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.texto_descritivo {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 390px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.texto_subdescritivo {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.noticiaarea2 {
    width: 310px;
    height: 420px;
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.noticiaitem {
    text-align: left;
    height: 88px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.noticia_img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    float: left;
}

.noticiatitulo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 216px;
}

.noticiainfo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #999;
    width: 216px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.footerint {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: roboto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1057px) {
    .topoint,
    .topo2int,
    .menuint,
    .ultimasnoticiasint,
    .containerint,
    .footerint {
        max-width: 890px;
    }
    .leftside {
        width: 600px;
    }
    .slide, .slideshow { /* alterado */
        max-width: 600px; /* adicionado */
    }
    .noticiaarea1 {
        width: 280px;
    }
    .noticia_image {
        width: 250px;
    }
    .noticia_image img {
        width: 250px;
    }
    .texto_descritivo {
        width: 250px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
  <div class="topoint">
      <div class="topoleft">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="./" class="ativo"> Home<a/></li>
        <li><a href="Quem somos">Quem Somos<a/></li>
        <li><a href="Anuncie aqui">Anuncie Aqui<a/></li>
        <li><a href="Contato">Contato<a/></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
    <div class="toporight">
      <input type="image" border="0" src="assets/images/lupabranca.png" width="26" height="26" >
      <input type="text" name="busca" class="topobusca" placeholder="Busca..." >
      <a href=""><img src="assets/images/youtube.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="assets/images/twitter.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="assets/images/facebook.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="assets/images/googleplus.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="assets/images/rss.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="topo2">
  <div class="topo2int">
      <div class="logo">
          <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" border="0" width="230" />
      </div>
      <div class="banner">
          PUBLICIDADE 80 X 650
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menuint">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="./" class="ativo">Home<a/></li>
    <li><a href="./" >Economia<a/></li>
    <li>
      <a href="./" >Entretenimento<a/>
      <img src="assets/images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10"/>
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
              <a href="./">
                  <div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div>
              </a>
              <a href="./">
                  <div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div>
              </a>
              <a href="./">
                  <div class="submenuitem">submenu4</div>
              </a>
              <a href="./">
                  <div class="submenuitem">submenu5</div>
              </a>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="./">Esportes<a/>
      <img src="assets/images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10">
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
      <a href="./">
          <div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div>
      </a>
      <a href="./">
          <div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div>
      </a>
</div>
</li>
<li><a href="./">Geral<a/></li>
    <li>
      <a href="./" >Notícias<a/>
      <img src="assets/images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10">
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
  <a href="./">
      <div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="./">
      <div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="./">
      <div class="submenuitem">submenu4</div>
  </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li><a href="./">policia<a/></li>
    <li><a href="./" >Videos<a/></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ultimasnoticias">
  <div class="ultimasnoticiasint">
    <div class="ultnoticiasarea">
       <div class="ultnoticiastitulo">ÚLTIMAS NOTÍCIAS</div>
       <div class="ultnoticiasnoticia">Alguma nótícia de algum texto que vai aparecer aqui...</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerint">
      <div class="leftside">
          <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
                <div class="bolls">
                    <div class="boll" onclick="mudarSlide(0)"></div>
                    <div class="boll" onclick="mudarSlide(1)"></div>
                    <div class="boll" onclick="mudarSlide(2)"></div>
                    <div class="boll" onclick="mudarSlide(3)"></div>
                </div>
               <div class="slideshow_area">
                  <a href="http://br.ufc.com/">
                  <div class="slide">
                       <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
                      <div class="slideinfo">
                   <div class="slideinfo_titulo">Um tiulo de teste para esse slide</div>
                 <div class="slideinfo_subtitulo">Subtitulo de teste para esse slide</div>
              </div>
           </div>
           </a>
  <a href="http://sicnoticias.sapo.pt/">
      <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
          <div class="slideinfo">
              <div class="slideinfo_titulo">Um tiulo de teste para esse slide</div>
              <div class="slideinfo_subtitulo">Subtitulo de teste para esse slide</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.nfl.com/">
      <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
          <div class="slideinfo">
              <div class="slideinfo_titulo">Um tiulo de teste para esse slide</div>
              <div class="slideinfo_subtitulo">Subtitulo de teste para esse slide</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/index.html">
      <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
          <div class="slideinfo">
              <div class="slideinfo_titulo">Um tiulo de teste para esse slide</div>
              <div class="slideinfo_subtitulo">Subtitulo de teste para esse slide</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget_titulo">NOTÍCIAS</div>
      <div class="widget_conteudo">
          <div class="noticiaarea1">
              <div class="noticiaitem1">
                  <div class="noticia_image">
                      <img src="assets/images/quadrilha.jpg" border="0" width="390" height="220">
                  </div>
                  <div class="texto_descritivo">Algum texto descritivo que vai aparecer por aqui abaixo dessa imagem</div>
                  <div class="texto_subdescritivo"> 1250 likes 500 comentários</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noticiaarea2">
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/jogo.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/rihanna.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/vint Cerf.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget_titulo">NOTÍCIAS RECENTES</div>
      <div class="widget_conteudo">
          <div class="noticiaarea1">
              <div class="noticiaitem1">
                  <div class="noticia_image">
                      <img src="assets/images/empresa.jpg" border="0" width="390" height="220">
                  </div>
                  <div class="texto_descritivo">Algum texto descritivo que vai aparecer por aqui abaixo dessa imagem</div>
                  <div class="texto_subdescritivo"> 1250 likes 500 comentários</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noticiaarea2">
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/escritorio.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/paisagem.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
              <div class="noticiaitem">
                  <div class="noticia_img">
                      <img src="assets/images/carro.jpg" border="0" width="80" height="80">
                  </div>
                  <div class="noticiatitulo">Algum titulo qualquer</div>
                  <div class="noticiainfo">500 comentários</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
      <div class="footer">
          <div class="footerint">© 2018. Todos os direitos reservados</div>
      </div>
  </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
      <div class="widget">
          <div class="widget_titulo">SOCIAL</div>
          <div class="widget_conteudo">
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/rss.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/googleplus.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/facebook.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/twitter.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/youtube.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
          <div class="widget_titulo">ULTIMAS NOTÍCIAS</div>
          <div class="widget_conteudo">
              <div class="noticia_item">
                  <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                   aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                </div>
                   <div class="noticia_item">
                   <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                   aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                </div>
                 <div class="noticia_item">
                   <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                   aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                </div>
                 <div class="noticia_item">
                   <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                   aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                </div>
                 <div class="noticia_item">
                   <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                   aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
          <div class="widget">
             <div class="widget_titulo">PUBLICIDADADE</div>
            <div class="widget_conteudo">
                <img src="assets/images/girl.jpg" border="0" width="275" >
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="widget">
             <div class="widget_titulo">ENCONTRE-NOS NO FACEBOOK</div>
            <div class="widget_conteudo">
            <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnike&tabs=timeline&width=272&height=465&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" width="272" height="465" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fiz como vc disse, mais quando diminuo a pagina para os 1057 px estabelicidos o site quebra, como resolver isso?

Comment: Stephan, tente deixando a classe `.leftside {` com os 600px mesmo para fazer um teste.

Comment: Funcionou, so que quando eu volto a tela pro tamnaho original as imagens dentro slide não acompanham e ficam aparecendo a metade de cada uma e quebra o slide ai preciso dar um f5 pra voltar o normal, e ai? tem um jeito de corrigir isso?

Comment: Atualizei a parte do `@media only screen and (max-width:1057px) {`... me parece que a resolução mínima é de 600px, então deixei algumas classes com 600px fixo.

Comment: Agora funcionou certinho rs, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Olá, estou prosseguindo co a responsividade do projeto, e agora estou com um problema na minha logo e na div de navegação ultimas noticias. A logo está ficando colada no topo o portal, enquanto o menu de navegação ultimas noticias não esta adaptando a largura do restante do conteudo, pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Onde posso postar os codigos pra vc dar uma olhada?

Comment: Opa! Daqui a pouco falo com vc, blz?

Comment: Certo amigo, sem problemas!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78100/discussion-between-stephan-viana-and-dvd).

Comment: Tô no chat.....

Comment: ei amigo, vai la no chat tive mais alguns problemas.